# MySQL query: Get totals from two non-related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have to query two tables:

table1:

```
+------+-----------+-------+
| id   |   atual   |  user |
+------+-----------+-------+
| 1    |   100     |  1    |
| 2    |   150     |  1    |
| 3    |   50      |  2    |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

table2:

```
+------+------------+-------+
| id   |   budget   |  user |
+------+------------+-------+
| 1    |   80       |  3    |
| 2    |   150      |  1    |
| 3    |   200      |  2    |
+------+------------+-------+
```

I want to grab the totals for user 1.

The two tables are not related. They have the user key in common, though.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(atual), SUM(budget) 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE user=1
```

Which is generating the error:

```
#1630 - FUNCTION SUM does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(atual), 
   (SELECT SUM(budget) FROM table2 WHERE user=1)
FROM table1
WHERE user=1
```

Comment: As a note:  this will not work if there are users in `table2` that are not in `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(table1.atual) as Actual, SUM(table2.budget)  as Budget
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.user=1
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'user' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: sorry both the table has user field so you must use the name of the table from which you want the user to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the aggregation before the `join`:

```
select a.actual, b.budget
from (select sum(actual) as actual from table1) a cross join
     (select sum(budget) as budget from table2) b;
```

EDIT:

When you say "The two tables are not related" in a question, it would certainly seem that you don't care about the user column.  I think you really want this:

```
select user, sum(actual) as actual, sum(budget) as budget
from ((select user, sum(actual) as actual, NULL as budget
       from table1
       group by user
      ) union all
      (select user, NULL as actual, sum(budget) as budget
       from table2
       group by user
      )
     ) ab
group by user
```